# Network line speed 1G on one switch and 10Mbps at the other switch to the router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

Hi I have a strange issue.  I have a network setup with wiring in the wall using cat 6.  The one has a keystone in the wall and the other location comes to a wiring closet with a home databus with 5e connectors where the wires wire into a TIA-568A Category 5e Compliant ChannelPlus model H628.

- My tplink switch reads 1G speed coming from the keystone from the wall
- At the databus location it is reading 10Mbps on the TpLink router.
- When I put another tp link switch in between the router and the databus it also shows 10Mbps
  I am very confused as to why I am seeing 1G speeds at the keystone but then from the databus it is showing 10Mbps.  I would think it would be 10Mbps on both sides if the wiring was faulty.  I tried changing all the patch cables from computer to switches to keystone and at the databus in the closet but it didn't change anything. I even tried changing the switch and it did nothing.  Does anyone have any ideas on what else to try or why this would be happening?  Other connections from the databus to the router are showing 1G into the router. Note: Wifi is a separate mesh network off of the wired only tplink router so wifi is not an issue here.

dell computer <--> tp link switch <--> keystone jack in wall (1G speed shown on switch on both the connections to the switch)

closet databus --> tp link router ( tp link router showing orange and only 10Mpbs)

when trying closet databus --> tplink switch --> tplink router  ( switch and router both showing 10Mbps)

Thanks for your help!